# Using existing SQLite database in Cayenne

Tags: java, sqlite, apache-cayenne

I've been playing around with Apache Cayenne in an IntelliJ project.
I configure the JDBC in the datanode like in the image but it gives me an error
[image: the screen]

I have the Cayenne project stored in my IntelliJ project folder, as well as the SQLite database "data.db".

Can anyone help me figuring out this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell CayenneModeler GUI where to find SQLite jar. To do that on Windows, go to Tools > Preferences > ClassPath and add a path to your SQLLite jar.

Answer (score 0):

It works with cayenne 3.1.1 and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/overview